# Remove support for Apple Watch on app store

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I removed the embedded app extension for my watch app, and the target dependency so that my app would discontinue support for the apple watch.

The app never quite worked, and the more my app evolves the less the apple watch does for the user.

After removing these things I attempted to install the build on my phone. It never was able to do so, until I deleted it.

I tested this using testflight.

The app won't install. It downloads, then sits at about 90%. Will NOT update

How then am I to remove support for the apple watch????

Comment: You might have to create a new project. Move all your files and change the Bundle ID to fit the same on as the app on test flight.

Comment: Did you ever find this out?

Comment: You could have had an issue with Provisioning Profile or app ids

Answer (score 0):

This answer may seem weird as it does not have to do with apple watch at all, but I have had the issue you've had with installs not finishing before. I was really stumped as to what it could be, looking into all of my extensions as you are doing now.

It ended up being that I had placed leading zeros in the version number/build number.

For example: Version 4.01
Instead of: Version 4.1

For some reason this caused the error you described for me. Can you confirm you don't have any leading zeros?